# Similiar routes/pages in Flask - how to remove duplication

Tags: python, flask

I have got a few subpages which look very similiar:
They are almost the same but each of them presents different currency:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/dollar', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def dollar_page():
    form = MyTextForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        values = app.process(request.form["values"])
    labels = get_data()
    return render_template('currency.html', currency="dollar", labels=labels, values=values)


@app.route('/euro', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def euro_page():
    form = MyTextForm()
    sentiment = ""
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        values = app.process(request.form["values"])
    labels = get_data()
    return render_template('currency.html', currency="euro", labels=labels, values=values)

 @app.route('/pound', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def pound_page():
 ... etc ...
```

What is the best way to get rid of this duplication in Flask applications? Is there any pattern? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable in your route to receive the type of currency. The route variable is passed as an argument to the view function. The `/` route doen't have the variable, so provide a default in that case.

```
import functools
def verify_currency(f):
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def wrapper(currency_type):
     if currency_type not in ['dollars', 'euros']: #can add more currencies to list later
         return flask.render_template("error.html") #or redirect
      return f(currency_type)
  return wrapper

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'], defaults={'currency': 'euro'})
@app.route('/currency/<currency>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@verify_currency
def dollar_page(currency):
    form = MyTextForm()
    values = labels = None

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        values = app.process(request.form["values"])
        labels = get_data()

  return render_template('currency.html', currency=currency, labels=labels, values=values)
```

Comment: but you are not using "cur_type" at all? And how can check if I have got data for the currency? For example someone could try to do "currency/xyz" ?

Comment: @AlicjaGłowacka You can create an additional wrapper for the route. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: ok and how can I access these views then? something like url_for('currency/dollar') instead of url_for('dollar_page')?

Comment: @AlicjaGłowacka Yes. You can also redirect using `flask.redirect('/currency/dollar')`

Comment: Actually url_for('currency/dollar') does not work. I assume it is wrong? And is it good patern to use wrapper to verify or veryfying in the view function is also ok?

Comment: @AlicjaGłowacka Try `url_for('/currency/dollar')`. I do not know of any reason why not to use a a wrapper: it is beneficial for code reusability and simplicity.

Comment: I get : Could not build url for endpoint '/currency/dollar'. Did you mean 'index' instead?